# Export TeXShop macros

Tags: mac, editors, texshop

I am currently using two different computers to write my papers and slides with TeXShop : my personal one at home, and my office computer.

I am searching for a way to "synchronize" my TeXShop macros between the two computers, or at least export a macro I write on a computer to the other. Even some artisanal solution would suit me, like finding where the macros are saved on a computer and manually copy the files to the other.

For example I have a Beamer template that I constantly update, actually I am forced to keep the template on a file on my Dropbox to keep it synchronized, whereas I would like to save it as a macro.

I insist upon the fact that I am talking about TexShop macros, the ones we create/modify with the Macro editor menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To move all of the macros copy the `~/Library/TeXShop/Macros` folder from one computer and replace the one on the other system with that folder. Note: `~/Library` is the Library folder in your HOME folder. In recent versions of TeXShop you can open `~/Library/TeXShop` using the TeXShop->Open `~/Library/TeXShop` menu command.

To move selected Macros open the Macro Editor (Macros->Open Macro Editor…), select the macro(s) in the list on the left and then click on Macros->Save selection to file… (Note: that menu item only appears when the Macro Editor is active) to create a file with extension `.plist` and a name of your choice in the location of your choice. Copy that file to the other system. On the other system open TeXShop and the Macro Editor and click on Macros->Add macros from file… (again, only available when the Macro Editor is active). Drag and drop that `.plist` file onto the selection window and import the file. Once the macros are imported you can move them to your preferred location(s) on the menu in the list at the left side of the Macro Editor window and then Save the changes.

Comment: Those are the informations I was looking for, thanks ! Just a detail : do I need to move the entire `~/Library/TeXShop/Macros` folder (that is, the three files I am actually seeing in there) or just some specific files ? 

Also, I don't see the menu command you are talking about in the Open menu, whereas I believe I have the last version (3.85).

Comment: You could just move the `Macros_Latex.plist` file assuming you are using LaTeX. The files with names ending with ~ are backups. It doesn't hurt to replace the whole folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use a bash script to collect such application customization in one folder for backup purposes that may help:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "backup app config"

DIR_HB_BACKUP="/Users/bingol/Documents/hbBackup"

echo "-TeXShop"
cp -f /Users/bingol/Library/TeXShop/Macros/Macros_Latex.plist ${DIR_HB_BACKUP}/Macros_Latex.plist
```